# Why in ASP.NET Ajax Update Panel after any action javascript elements stop working?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am writing a web application in C# with ASP.NET. For performance I'd like to insert a `UserWebControl` in an `Update panel` to enable AJAX.

On the same `UserWebControl` I have a menu that is powered by jQuery. When the page loads, the menu is working perfectly but after some server side actions in the `Update Panel`, the menu and other javascript-based controls stop working.

Comment: I've updated your question. Please note that javascript and Java are two very different languages, despite the similarity in their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        //your jquery goes here
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand the problem exactly but i guess that after the page is loaded you are executing some JavaScript functions. Then when you update your UserControl using asp.net UpdatePanel it's actually being loaded again, then you need to execute your JavaScript functions again...